# Labeling top and bottom range cells where criteria is 1

Tags: excel, vba

Excel Table as below:

```
RowID, A, B, C
1, amazon.com,
2, amazon.com, 
3, amazon.com, ecommerce, 1
4, amazon.com, 
5, amazon.com, 
6, outlook.com, mailbox, 1
7, outlook.com, 
8, outlook.com,
9, outlook.com,
10, outlook.com,
11, cloudera.com, cloud services
```

Problem:

Look for value 1 in column C, get the value in Column B, fill up row 1-2 and row 4-5 with ecommerce since column A is amazon.com

Once it's done with amazon.com, look for the next value 1, fill up row 7-10 since column A is outlook.com

Expected output:

```
RowID, A, B, C
1, amazon.com, ecommerce
2, amazon.com, ecommerce
3, amazon.com, ecommerce, 1
4, amazon.com, ecommerce
5, amazon.com, ecommerce
6, outlook.com, mailbox, 1
7, outlook.com, mailbox
8, outlook.com, mailbox
9, outlook.com, mailbox
10, outlook.com, mailbox
11, cloudera.com, cloud services
```

What I have tried as below:

```
Sub test()    
    Dim ws As String
    Dim t, lr, fr, nr As Long

    ws = ActiveSheet.Name
    lr = Sheets(ws).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    t = 1
    nr = 1

    Do Until t = lr
        Set val1 = Sheets(ws).Range("C" & t & ":C" & lr).Cells.Find(what:="1")
        If Not val1 Is Nothing Then
            Set val2 = Sheets(ws).Range("B1:B" & lr).Cells.Find(what:="")
            fr = val2.Row - 1
            nr = val1.Row - 1

            Range("B" & fr).Copy
            Range("B" & fr + 1 & ":B" & nr).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If

        t = nr + 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

Any idea how to modify the code?

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: Why are you looking in Col C? Simplu check for data in col B and replicate? Or am I missing a point?

Comment: @SJR, it doesn't copy up

Comment: @SiddharthRout the point is the criteria 1, the 1 is basically a form of marker to perform the labeling process

Comment: But if there's a value in B every time there is 1 in C you want the former, no?

Comment: @SJR, refer to the expected output table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated code # 4**

Note that the code adds a "helper" formula into column D (it will be removed at the very end), so make sure there is nothing important in there.

```
Dim ws As String
Dim lr As Long, lngMatch As Long, lngEnd As Long, lngStart As Long
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim MatchFormula As String, EndFormula As String, StartFormula As String

ws = ActiveSheet.Name

With Sheets(ws)
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("D2:D" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-3]<>R[-1]C[-3],""s"",IF(AND(RC[-3]=R[-1]C[-3],RC[-3]=R[1]C[-3]),""m"",""e""))"
    For Each rngCell In .Range("B1:B" & lr)
        If Len(rngCell) = 0 Then
            If rngCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = rngCell.Offset(-1, -1).Value _
                Or rngCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = rngCell.Offset(1, -1).Value Then
                On Error Resume Next
                    StartFormula = "LOOKUP(2,1/($D$2:D" & rngCell.Row & "=""s""),ROW($D$2:D" & rngCell.Row & "))"
                    lngStart = Evaluate(StartFormula)
                    EndFormula = "MATCH(""e"",D" & rngCell.Row + 1 & ":$D$" & lr & ",0)"
                    lngEnd = Evaluate(EndFormula)
                    MatchFormula = "MATCH(1,($A$" & lngStart & ":$A$" & lngEnd + rngCell.Row & "=A" & rngCell.Row _
                        & ")*($C$" & lngStart & ":$C$" & lngEnd + rngCell.Row & "=1),0)"
                    lngMatch = Evaluate(MatchFormula)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If lngMatch Then
                    rngCell.Value = .Range("B" & lngStart + lngMatch - 1).Value
                End If
                lngEnd = 0
                lngMatch = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next rngCell
    .Range("D2:D" & lr).Clear
End With
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: nearly there, if cloudera.com is above amazon.com, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Glad it's almost correct! Could you provide me with a screenshot please and what kind of output would you expect? When I shifted cloudera.com above amazon.com it still seems to be correct -> [link](https://i.imgur.com/EuwLlaF.png)

Comment: got a screenshot here: https://imgur.com/yhFBakj, if you notice some of the labeling is wrong eg. google.com should be search engine, because it took it from the previous label where there is criteria 1. So basically it should only label where there is criteria 1

Comment: Ahh got it; sorry, didn't know that data is not sorted. Thanks for the screenshot, this is useful. I'll tweak my solution and post it back in a few minutes.

Comment: No problem! See updated answer - note that Header2 for some webpages is empty because there is no "category" provided for them marked with value `1`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: almost 9/10, is it doable to not label those without the value 1 as updated image: https://imgur.com/ftorw9n

Comment: Umm sorry, not sure if I understand - are you saying that you only want to have a label (column B) only if there is a value of `1` in the same row (column C)? I see that the first citibank has a label but there is no value `1` next to it, the same with the first two moneysmart.sg webpages, that's why I'm confused. Just want to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: Ignore me, I think I know what you're requesting... check my updated answer.

Comment: wow, 9.9/10! just some minor issue as shown: https://imgur.com/vgiTNIh, it doesnt label it down from value 1, otherwise it's perfect! good job!

Comment: You're welcome :) don't forget to upvote/mark the answer as correct if you're happy with it. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info. Take care